# terser-webpack-plugin doesn't support IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, terser-webpack-plugin

I've to update uglify-webpack-plugin due to server restrictions, so I found terser-webpack-plugin is in the suggestion, however it doesn't support IE11 by default.

It just shows a syntax error in the vendor.js file, while loading the app.

Anyone faced this issue before, please guide me. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a webpack setup with .browserslistrc ?

Comment: As far as I know, most of these plugin scripts use `es6` syntax, and IE11 is not compatible with it, IE11 can only parse `es5` syntax, so you may need a transpiler such as [Babel-polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-polyfill). If possible, could you provide more details, like error message in devtool console?